# Self Assigned IP Address w/ iPhone and iPad At One Single Location

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

This is at a coffee shop that I have been visiting regularly for four or five years. At the this one place both devices (iPhone 6s and iPad mini 4) always get a self-assigned IP address. As I recall, on only one occasion out of well over a hundred visits, have the devices been assigned an address via DHCP. If I manually enter an IP address, Netmask, etc., both devices connect immediately and work fine.

What I have tried:

- Forget This Network: Dozens of times
- Reset Network Settings: Half a dozen times
- Factory Reset iPhone: Once

Nothing seems to work.

I have asked other customers about this. No one has the same problem. I have asked the company's IT department, suggesting that they reduce the lease time, but they say no one else has the same problem.

This company has many coffee shops. I regularly visit several of them. Every shop uses the same SSID and password. I thought this might be part of the problem, but my daughter recently got a job with this company and she takes her iPhone 7 from shop to shop regularly and never has trouble connecting. She also tells me that they have no reports from other customers having difficulty connecting.

The router at this one shop is a small ZTE router. The other shops, as far as I have determined, use TP-Link routers.

Any ideas how to fix this on my iPhone and iPad?